# Get all corda accounts through API

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

I am trying to get all of the accounts that are available on a certain node.

I am using the below code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/accounts/all", method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    fun allKnownAccounts(): List<AccountInfoView> {
      return getAllAccounts().map { it.toAccountView() }
    }

    private fun getAllAccounts() = rpc.proxy.startFlowDynamic(AllAccounts::class.java, false).returnValue.get()
```

But i am getting the below error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   net.corda.core.flows.IllegalFlowLogicException: A FlowLogicRef cannot be constructed for FlowLogic of type com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.AllAccounts: due to ambiguous match against the constructors: [class java.lang.Boolean]

i am not sure what is causing the exception to occur. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating the getAllAccounts() function to the below:

```
    private fun getAllAccounts() = rpc.proxy.startFlowDynamic(AllAccounts::class.java).returnValue.get()
```